# Where can i(ContentsOwner, MCN) find Finalized Red(Premium)&Superchat revenue data in Youtube reporting API?

Tags: python, google-api-php-client, youtube-analytics-api

Can't find **reportTypeId** or **Job** which have **"Youtube Red Partner Revenue Report"** and **"Paid features Report"** in Youtube reporting API

Im recently developing system for creator's revenue report.

As i know My company(Contents Owner, MCN) have 3 kinds of revenue source from youtube which is

1. Ads Partner Revenue
2. YouTube Red Partner Revenue (Youtube Premium)
3. Paid Features (Superchat)

So i looked up to APIs and found reporting API that [supports System managed reports for contents owners](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/system_managed/)!
but i can not find revenue report of 2) YouTube Red Partner Revenue 3) Paid Features (Superchat)

list below are system managed reportTypes that i find in API
(All reports are systemManaged)

1. "id": "content_owner_ad_revenue_raw_a1","name": "Monthly video ad revenue"
2. "id": "content_owner_ad_revenue_summary_a1", "name": "Monthly video ad revenue summary"
3. "id": "content_owner_asset_ad_revenue_raw_a1", "name": "Monthly asset ad revenue"
4. "id": "content_owner_asset_ad_revenue_summary_a1", "name": "Monthly asset ad revenue summary"
5. "id": "content_owner_claim_ad_revenue_summary_a1", "name": "Monthly claim ad revenue"

so i retrieved/created reports and sum it.

But i found that **{}_ad_revenue_{}** kinds of reports only have 1) Ads Partner Revenue data.

## where can i find Youtube Red(Premium) and Superchat revenue data from Youtube reporting api?

I have Oauth tokens of scopes

1. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"
2. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"
3. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner"
4. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly"

---

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import HttpError

if __name__ == "__main__":
    yt_credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN)
    yt_service = build(YOUTUBE_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VER, credentials=yt_credentials)
    results = yt_service.reportTypes().list(includeSystemManaged=True,
                                               onBehalfOfContentOwner='MY Content Owner Id').execute()

    print(json.dumps(results, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: YOUTUBE_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtubereporting'
YOUTUBE_API_VER = 'v1'

Comment: I think that System Managed Reports does not contain those types of reports. [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/system_managed/)  it is specified that System Managed Reports contains "**ad revenue reports** for content owners".  Maybe someone from Google or a more experienced developer with Youtube Reporting API could confirm (or not).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently visited one of YouTube webinars and asked that same question, and I can confirm that YouTube reports available through Reporting API **do not currently contain** neither YouTube Premium (Red) revenue nor paid features (Superchat is one of paid features as you probably know) revenue reports.

YouTube is planning to implement those but did not give any timeline for that.